# performance - drawing many 2d circles in opengl

Tags: performance, opengl, gpu, geometry, particles

I am trying to draw large numbers of 2d circles for my 2d games in opengl. They are all the same size and have the same texture. Many of the sprites overlap. What would be the fastest way to do this?

[an example of the kind of effect I'm making http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/6379/circles.png](http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/6379/circles.png)

(It should be noted that the black edges are just due to the expanding explosion of circles. It was filled in a moment after this screen-shot was taken.

At the moment I am using a pair of textured triangles to make each circle. I have transparency around the edges of the texture so as to make it look like a circle. Using blending for this proved to be very slow (and z culling was not possible as they were rendered as squares to the depth buffer). Instead I am not using blending but having my fragment shader discard any fragments with an alpha of 0. This works, however it means that early z is not possible (as fragments are discarded).

The speed is limited by the large amounts of overdraw and the gpu's fillrate. The order that the circles are drawn in doesn't really matter (provided it doesn't change between frames creating flicker) so I have been trying to ensure each pixel on the screen can only be written to once.

I attempted this by using the depth buffer. At the start of each frame it is cleared to 1.0f. Then when a circle is drawn it changes that part of the depth buffer to 0.0f. When another circle would normally be drawn there it is not as the new circle also has a z of 0.0f. This is not less than the 0.0f that is currently there in the depth buffer so it is not drawn. This works and should reduce the number of pixels which have to be drawn. However; strangely it isn't any faster. I have already asked a question about this behavior ([opengl depth buffer slow when points have same depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949375/opengl-depth-buffer-slow-when-points-have-same-depth/14949763)) and the suggestion was that z culling was not being accelerated when using equal z values.

Instead I have to give all of my circles separate false z-values from 0 upwards. Then when I render using glDrawArrays and the default of GL_LESS we correctly get a speed boost due to z culling (although early z is not possible as fragments are discarded to make the circles possible). However this is not ideal as I've had to add in large amounts of z related code for a 2d game which simply shouldn't require it (and not passing z values if possible would be faster). This is however the fastest way I have currently found.

Finally I have tried using the stencil buffer, here I used

```
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0, 1);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_INCR, GL_INCR);
```

Where the stencil buffer is reset to 0 each frame. The idea is that after a pixel is drawn to the first time. It is then changed to be none-zero in the stencil buffer. Then that pixel should not be drawn to again therefore reducing the amount of overdraw. However this has proved to be no faster than just drawing everything without the stencil buffer or a depth buffer.

What is the fastest way people have found to write do what I am trying?

Comment: are you drawing them in a single batch?

Comment: Yes, just one glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 100001*(2*3)); per frame draws all of them.

Comment: hmm I would anticipate fairly good results - When the window is smaller is it faster?

Comment: Yes. It is considerably faster.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem is that you're *fill limited*, which is the GPUs inability to shade all the fragments you ask it to draw in the time you're expecting.  The reason that you're depth buffering trick isn't effective is that the most time-comsuming part of processing is shading the fragments (either through your own fragment shader, or through the fixed-function shading engine), which occurs *before* the depth test.  The same issue occurs for using stencil; shading the pixel occurs before stenciling.

There are a few things that may help, but they depend on your hardware:

- render your sprites from front to back with depth buffering.  Modern GPUs often try to determine if a collection of fragments will be visible before sending them off to be shaded.  Roughly speaking, the depth buffer (or a represenation of it) is checked to see if the fragment that's about to be shaded will be visible, and if not, it's processing is terminated at that point.  This should help reduce the number of pixels that need to be written to the framebuffer.
- Use a fragment shader that immediately checks your texel's alpha value, and discards the fragment before any additional processing, as in:

  ```
  varying vec2 texCoord;
  uniform sampler2D tex;

  void main()
  {
      vec4 texel = texture( tex, texCoord );

      if ( texel.a < 0.01 ) discard;

      // rest of your color computations
  }
  ```

(you can also use alpha test in fixed-function fragment processing, but it's impossible to say if the test will be applied before the completion of fragment shading).

Comment: I may have been unclear. If I give each circle a different value on the z axis it's actually over twice as fast (in my test) as not using depth buffering at all. However depth buffering with the same value of z for the circles is not noticeably faster than doing no z buffering at all. (it seeming like it should work just as well?) This may be because of your first point. (Which is interesting as that sounds like early z? I thought it was not possible if you discard in the fragment shader?) My fragment shader is just like that. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Ellipsis Using depth buffering makes sense over not: at least you can save a bunch of read-modify-write cycles to the color and depth buffers, so I'm not surprised there.  As for using the same z value, I don't know.  It could be that there's a fast mode for less-than depth testing, or equal mode yields basically the same result as not-depth testing.  Finally, there are architectures which disable early-z if you do this trick, but it's not a universal trait of all GPUs - it's an implementation issue, and something you only find by testing.  And, you're welcome.